# Firebase Verifying ID Tokens

Tags: node.js, firebase, firebase-authentication

I have a server app and I'm trying to identify the currently signed-in user on that server. I have successfully authenticated the user on my web app like this:

```
    var provider = new firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider();          
    firebase.auth().signInWithPopup(provider).then(function(result) {
        userJsonToken = result.credential.accessToken;
        user = result.user;
    }).catch(function(error) {
        // Handle Errors here.
        var errorCode = error.code;
        var errorMessage = error.message;
        // The email of the user's account used.
        var email = error.email;
        // The firebase.auth.AuthCredential type that was used.
        var credential = error.credential;
    });
```

I then send the userJsonToken to my server via an ajax call and I can see the token when I debug so the token is being correctly sent to the server.

In my server application I am doing this:

```
try (InputStream is = FirebaseUtil.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(FIREBASE_CREDENTIALS_JSON_FILE)) {
    FirebaseOptions options = new FirebaseOptions.Builder().setServiceAccount(is).setDatabaseUrl(FIREBASE_DATABASE_URL).build();        
    FirebaseApp.initializeApp(options);
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace(System.err);
}
```

Then I do:

```
    FirebaseAuth.getInstance().verifyIdToken(idToken).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {            
        @Override
        public void onFailure(Exception ex) {
            throw new AuthenticationServiceException(ex.getMessage(), ex);
        }
    }).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<FirebaseToken>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(FirebaseToken token) {
            System.out.println("Yeehaw");
        }
    }).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<FirebaseToken>() {          
        @Override
        public void onComplete(Task<FirebaseToken> arg0) {
            System.out.println(arg0.isSuccessful());
        }
    });
```

At this point, the OnFailureListener is getting called. I am getting a java.lang.IllegalArgumentException with no explanation about why or what has happened. Is there anyway I can see logs on Firebase that will shed some light on what has happened? Thanks

This is the complete error:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
at com.google.api.client.repackaged.com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkArgument(Preconditions.java:111)
at com.google.api.client.util.Preconditions.checkArgument(Preconditions.java:37)
at com.google.api.client.json.webtoken.JsonWebSignature$Parser.parse(JsonWebSignature.java:602)
at com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseToken.parse(FirebaseToken.java:81)
at com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth$1.call(FirebaseAuth.java:143)
at com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth$1.call(FirebaseAuth.java:140)
at com.google.firebase.tasks.Tasks$1.run(Tasks.java:63)
```

Comment: Did you ever find a resolution to this? I'm now hitting the exact same error as well, and am confused as to how to debug it, given that the exception gives no information at all

Answer (score 1):

Ran into this problem myself, and after not finding an answer here, decided to look into the source-code itself.

```
/**
 * Parses a JWS token into a parsed {@link JsonWebSignature}.
 *
 * @param tokenString JWS token string
 * @return parsed {@link JsonWebSignature}
 */
public JsonWebSignature parse(String tokenString) throws IOException {
  // split on the dots
  int firstDot = tokenString.indexOf('.');
  Preconditions.checkArgument(firstDot != -1);
  byte[] headerBytes = Base64.decodeBase64(tokenString.substring(0, firstDot));
  int secondDot = tokenString.indexOf('.', firstDot + 1);
  Preconditions.checkArgument(secondDot != -1);
  ...
```

In particular, this was the line that triggered the error in your case:

```
  Preconditions.checkArgument(secondDot != -1);
```

Apparently, if your token does not have at least 2 dots, it will produce an IllegalArgumentException here, without any error-message clarifying why this error was thrown.

In my case I hit this error because I was using a fake token that I made up by hand, for testing purposes. I was expecting to see a "token decode failed" type error. Sure enough, after adding 2 dots to my fake-token, I then run into a far more descriptive error message:

`Decoding Firebase ID token failed. Make sure you passed the entire string JWT which represents an ID token. See https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/verify-id-tokens for details on how to retrieve an ID token.`

It's unfortunate that the Firebase team didn't include a more descriptive error message for the first 2 preconditions, because that would better alert users to the fact that the token is malformed/incomplete, and that there is nothing wrong with the way they initialized or invoked FirebaseAuth.